# how to set value for date and amount(currency) in default constructor in corda

Tags: corda

how to set value for date and amount(currency) field default constructor (in schema) in corda programs. I tried commenting the constructor but met with error in API.

Comment: Please add an example of what you tried to do, see the instructions on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will help us to answer your question faster and better.

Comment: @Column(name = "TradeId")
            var TradeId: Date,                                           @Column(name = "linear_id")
            var linearId: UUID
 constructor(): this("",UUID.randomUUID())

Comment: Thanks, but please use the edit button to add this information to your original post. And when you do, make sure to format it, as you can see how to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a schema with a default value for one of the fields, `value`:

```
object IOUSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(
        schemaFamily = IOUSchema.javaClass,
        version = 1,
        mappedTypes = listOf(PersistentIOU::class.java)) {
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "iou_states")
    class PersistentIOU(
            @Column(name = "lender")
            var lenderName: String,

            @Column(name = "borrower")
            var borrowerName: String,

            @Column(name = "linear_id")
            var linearId: UUID,

            @Column(name = "value")
            var value: Int = 93
    ) : PersistentState() {
        // Default constructor required by hibernate.
        constructor(): this("", "", UUID.randomUUID(), 0)
    }
}
```

If you don't provide a value for this field, then the default value of `93` will be used. For example:

```
override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
    return when (schema) {
        is IOUSchemaV1 -> IOUSchemaV1.PersistentIOU(
                this.lender.name.toString(),
                this.borrower.name.toString(),
                this.linearId.id
        )
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Column(name = "lendingdate")
            var value: lendingdate,                                                                         constructor(): this("", "", UUID.randomUUID(), 0,?).                                  what value should be given for the feild lendingdate in the default comstructor.

Comment: What's the type of `lendingdate`?

Comment: data type is Date.

Comment: Try `new Date()`